# How to temporarily suspend iTunes Connect payments for app earnings?

Tags: app-store-connect, developer-program

I should temporarily suspend Apple's payments for sales of my apps on AppStore.
Other markets allow you to change the minimum amount to receive your payments, or suspend payments for a few months. Is there any way to do it on iTunes Connect as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust your app's price tier in iTunes Connect, including making it free and including setting start and end dates for the price tier change.

See [these instructions from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW8) for details of the steps to take for the app itself.

See [these instructions from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/WorkingWithYourProductsStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH33-SW5) for details of the steps to take for an in-app-purchase.

Comment: Thanks, I know that I can offer my apps or in-app for free for a period of time, often I did during promotional periods. But this is not my question. I would like to continue to sell my applications but delay payments for a few months, as can be done on other marketplaces.